# Powershell regex replacement

Tags: powershell

i want to replace regex text in the subdirectory file using PowerShell.

```
C:\file\new\test_file.zip
C:\file\old\test_test_file.zip
```

output

```
C:\file\new\file.zip
C:\file\old\file.zip
```

if I run the following script from powershell ISE, it's working fine. but if I run this as .ps1 script, it gives error. it's most likely the regex is wrong. any suggestion where am I doing it wrong?

```
Get-ChildItem -path C:\file -Recurse -File| rename-item -NewName { $_.name –replace "(test_)","" }
```

Comment: try `$_.Name -replace '(test_)+'`

Comment: "*it gives error.*" - what error?

Comment: The dash before replace is a 0x2016 "en dash".  Can't save as utf8nobom.

Comment: this is the error i getting: ```+ ... I -Recurse -File| rename-item -NewName { $_.Name â€“replace "(test_)+ ...
+                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'â€“replace "' in expression or statement.```

Comment: My question is how did you put an en dash before replace?  If you delete that and put a regular dash it should be fine.

Comment: sorry, probably it was a typing mistake. thank you so much!